# Lua: Capturing String Based on Number of Symbols Received

Tags: string, loops, lua

I currently have a string that can be any length in size based on a single digit in **one or two** specific locations (based on the first digit captured).  For example:

**Changed**

---

First digit captured tells me IF a file name is to follow: "1" = Object Name Follows.  "0" = Next input captured is Length Multiplier.
"1" is not always received.  But "0" is always received.

With "1" Capture it looks like this:
`START|(1)|NAMEOFGRAPHIC|(0)|(#)|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|... etc`

With "0" (no "1" captured)
`START|(0)|(#)|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|... etc`

The Length Multiplier bit (always follows "0") is the number of INPUT groups to follow.  A "group" is a set of 4x`INPUT`'s.  So, if it was a "4", the string I want to completely capture looks like this:

With a "1":
`START|(1)|NAMEOFGRAPHIC|(0)|(4)|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|`

With a "0":
`START|(0)|(4)|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|`

---

As each INPUT is received, a pipe symbol is added after.  I want to use the pipes to monitor the length of the input based on the digit.  If the digit is `5`, for example, it would capture the 3x `INPUT`, `5`, then 5x `INPUT` after (with all pipes included).  Once this is done, the function would send the fully captured string to other function(s) for use.

I am having problems working out the receiving function to capture this full string.  I have tried to count the number of pipes in different loop functions and all are resulting in errors.

Attempts include (please understand I'm pretty new to all of this):

```
local buffer = ""
function pipe_count(input)
    a = "|"
    buffer = buffer..input.."|"
    while #a < 5 do
        buffer = buffer..input.."|"
        return buffer
    end
end
```

---

```
local buffer = ""
function pipe_count(input)
    buffer = buffer..input.."|"
    mult = tonumber(buffer:match("(.-|.-|.-|(%d)|.*)"))
    while buffer do
        for i = 1, mult do
            buffer = buffer..input.."|"
        end
    return buffer
end
```

---

Those were two examples I tried.  I deleted my other futile attempts to capture the exact string length.  My current issue that it is taking the `INPUT` captures, as each one is received, and sending it to the next function prior to capturing the entire string.  So, if I had received the string at the top, it would look like this:

```
`INPUT`
`INPUT|INPUT`
`INPUT|INPUT|INPUT`
`INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|5`
`INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|5|INPUT`
`INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|5|INPUT|INPUT` etc
```

until finally the string below is received:

```
`INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|5|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|INPUT|`
```

At this point, my file runs as it should.  But up until this point, I'm getting errors since the parameters of the function(s) aren't fully met.

Ideally, I want that last string before moving on.

Any ideas would be very welcomed and appreciated.

Cheers

ETA: These `INPUT`'s are filling a buffer.  I want that check digit to be responsible for the string to only be used if the length value is met. Again, I really appreciate all input.  Thank you.

ETA: Example code tried and more input details.

Comment: @BenGrimm I hope that clarifies a little more?

Comment: @BenGrimm Each input is a string in itself; varying data including alphanumeric characters.  Each input is entered into a buffer concatenated with the pipe deliminators.  This continues to build until the buffer is the finalized string I can use later on.  I don't know if I'm being to vague or not.  Please let me know.

Comment: @BenGrimm Some more specific examples have been updated in my original post.  "1" is not always received.  But "0" is always sent down with a "Length Multiplier" to follow.  The "Length Multiplier" gets multiplied by "4" and that will result in the total number of INPUTs that need to be captured after the multiplier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All strings in Lua are internalized, so it's usually a better idea to push strings onto an array than to repeatedly rebuild the same string. This example takes input line by line from stdin. 3 data inputs, followed by a number, followed by that number of data inputs. There are plenty of other ways to do it, but this is pretty easy to follow.

```
local buffer = {}
function process_input(input)
    if #buffer == 3 then
        input = tonumber(input)
    end

    table.insert(buffer,input)

    if #buffer > 4 and #buffer == buffer[4] + 4 then
       local pipe_delim = table.concat(buffer,'|')
       buffer = {}
       return pipe_delim
    end
end

repeat
    local input = io.read()

    local pipe_delim = process_input( input )
    if pipe_delim then
       print('Got:', pipe_delim)
    end
until false
```

Comment: Thanks!  In reviewing and manipulating your code to fit my needs, I completely forgot a detail in my inputs that I had to share and change above.  If you do not feel like modifying your answer to include that information, I understand.  I'll try to see if I can work on it myself.  I think I know where you were going.  I would just have to include if #buffer equaled numerous positions, etc.  But thank you so much!!!

Comment: I've updated the examples to display what I mean.  I hope that it clarifies enough that you, or another member, and provide another solution to my problem which I may base my code from.  Again, thank you for your input so far.

Comment: With your update you've basically coded it yourself :-) Just add a couple of variables to retain state and and reference them in each processing pass.

Comment: Hmmm.... Can you provide an example of what you mean please?  Do you mean that I have to declare variable to represent each input in the order they are received? And if so, how would you approach the sequence of inputs based on the "length multiplier" ?

Comment: No, you just need to have variables to flag indicate where you are in the processing sequence so when your code receives the next input it can decide what to do with it. *It's just a matter of programming it* -- go through the process on paper and think it through. i.e. Am I still in the preamble to the inputs? Yes: did I get a "1" last time? if so, do this, else do that; No: gather inputs until I've reached the count I found earlier.

Comment: Excellent response. Thank you Ben.  I'll mark your code as the answer. You were a huge help.